# how to do while loop in sql

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

i need to execute loop until @ss return null or number of "-". so tried below code

```
DECLARE @i int,@ss varchar(20)
SET @i=1;
--WHILE (@ss =null)
WHILE(@i<=3)// i need to assign i value dynamically 
BEGIN
SET @ss =(SELECT dbo.GetStringPart('-','hello-world',@i))
PRINT @ss
SET @i =@i+1
END
```

Function: GetStringPart

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetStringPart] (@sep varchar(1), @s varchar(512),@pos int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(200)
;WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
  FROM Pieces
  WHERE stop > 0
)
SELECT
  @output=SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END)
FROM Pieces
WHERE pn=@pos
RETURN @Output
END
```

how to do it.thanks...

Comment: why don't you return a table from your function instead of this spaghetti code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IS` and `IS NOT` instead of `=` and `<>` to compare with NULL:

```
WHILE @ss IS NOT NULL
```

Oh, and to get the loop going the first time, give `@ss` a dummy initializer:

```
DECLARE @i int, @ss varchar(20) = ''
```